# News and Featured image

Tags: php, post-thumbnails

I am trying to list my news items in 3 columns in a vertical design: image, date, title. I'm having some trouble calling the featured image. Is there a specific function that would help me with this? Also add CSS style to list them in 3 columns?

Website Example: http://www.enterpriseflorida.com/why-florida/infrastructure/

My Code:

```
    <?php 
        $posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=2&order=DESC&orderby=post_title&category_name=news' );

        foreach ( $posts as $post ) : start_wp();
    ?>
            <?php toolbox_posted_on(); ?>
            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title() ; ?></a></h4>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn blue">Read All News</a>
```

Comment: Please leave feedback to the two answers given. Also, accept one if it solved your issue by clicking on the checkmark next to it

Answer (score 0):

The function for showing the featured image is http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

To show your content in columns best way would be to wrap your content in a html element then float it. eg.

In your template you might have:

```
<?php 
    $posts = get_posts('numberposts=2&order=DESC&orderby=post_title&category_name=news' );
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) : start_wp();

    echo "<div class='news_item'>";

        toolbox_posted_on();

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        } 
?>
        <h4>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_title() ; ?>
            </a>
         </h4>

<?php 
    echo "</div>";    
    endforeach; 
?>
```

Then you css would be something like:

```
.news_item {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

---

Updated Answer, with excerpt stuff

To customize the read more function you should read this page: [Customizing the Read more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

But in summary just use this:

```
// Replaces the excerpt "more" text by a link
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read the full article...</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: there is no need for the conditional check of the post thumbnail, unless you want to add extra html around it.

Comment: Thanks for your updated code. I am also calling some description of the text of the news with limited character with <?php the_excerpt() ;?> but I'm trying to figure out how to add a read more.. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the code you have in here is really outdated and has been deprecated for quite some time. I am going to use updated code so that it's more useful to those who will stumble on this thread.

```
<div class='news_item'>
    <?php 
    $posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=2&order=DESC&orderby=post_title&category_name=news' );

        foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);  ?>
            <?php toolbox_posted_on();

            //Check if post has thumbnail 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :

                //Output img tag automatically
                the_post_thumbnail();

            //Output
            ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <h4>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title() ; ?></a>
            </h4>
        <?php endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn blue">Read All News</a>
```

Your CSS

```
.news_item {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```